# Server host different on shell than the one on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect to my freshly created database. I'm connecting to my terminal and launch the command:

```
mysql -h maelmayon.mysql.db -u maelmayon -p xxx
```

Which is exactly what I'm using on PhpMyAdmin to access it (and it works) but it answer me:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'maelmayon.mysql.db' (0)
```

Is there a specification or a difference I shall be aware off?

[image]

This is what I've done, the first is a test in local, working well but after I may do something wrong.

Comment: Where is your mySQL server running, i.e. where is `maelmayon.mysql.db` and where have you defined this host name?

Comment: Did you run the terminal command on the webserver or the client?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Not sure I get what you've said, its a server hosed online with OVH (famous host). And by their client side online I can acces to php my admin.
I had a photo so you can see if I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your phpMyAdmin runs on the OVH server, your Mac doesn't. The database server is reachable only from the OVH server. You'd have to be able to log in to the server

Comment: @Pekka웃 So in a first time I should log to OVH ? Some link to provide ? Thank you for the answer anyway !

Comment: You'll have to find out with OVH whether you can log in to their server (it's called a SSH login). Chances are that feature isn't available, though, it rarely is with shared hosting.